# wso2 identity server custom handler reading from properties file

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

```html
public class UserRegistrationCustomEventHandler extends AbstractEventHandler {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserRegistrationCustomEventHandler.class);
    @Override
    public String getName() {

        return "customClaimUpdate";
    }
        
        if (IdentityEventConstants.Event.POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS.equals(event.getEventName())) {
            String tenantDomain = (String) event.getEventProperties()
                    .get(IdentityEventConstants.EventProperty.TENANT_DOMAIN);
            String userName = (String) event.getEventProperties().get(IdentityEventConstants.EventProperty.USER_NAME);
            Map<String, Object> eventProperties = event.getEventProperties();
            String eventName = event.getEventName();
            UserStoreManager userStoreManager = (UserStoreManager) eventProperties.get(IdentityEventConstants.EventProperty.USER_STORE_MANAGER);        
            // String userStoreDomain = UserCoreUtil.getDomainName(userStoreManager.getRealmConfiguration());
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String> claimValues = (Map<String, String>) eventProperties.get(IdentityEventConstants.EventProperty
                    .USER_CLAIMS);
            String emailId = claimValues.get("http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress");
            userName = "USERS/"+userName;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                json.put("userName",userName );
                json.put("emailId",emailId );
                
            log.info("JSON:::::::"+json);
            
            // Sample API
            //String apiValue = "http://192.168.1.X:8080/SomeService/user/updateUserEmail?email=sujith@gmail.com&userName=USERS/sujith";
                    try {
                            URL url = new URL(cityAppUrl) ;
                            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                            con.setDoOutput(true);
                            con.setDoInput(true);
                            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            log.info("CONN:::::::::::::"+con);
                            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                            os.write(cityAppUrl.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                            os.close();
                            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                            String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                            log.info("JSON OBJECT:::::::::"+jsonObject);    
                        } 
                        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }
         
    }

    @Override
    public void init(InitConfig configuration) throws IdentityRuntimeException {

        super.init(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPriority(MessageContext messageContext) {

        return 250;
    }
}
```

I'm using wso2 identity server 5.10.0 and have to push the updated claim value to an API so I'm using a custom handler and have subscribed to POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS, i have to read the API value from deployment.toml file in jave code of the custom handler. So can any one please help here to read the value from deployment file

I can fetch the updated claim value in logs but im not able to get the API value. So can anyone help me here to read the value from deployment file.

Comment: What is the deployment.toml config that you were trying to get from the code base? The java code reads the config files. deployment.toml is used just to change the configurations in config files like identity.xml, carbon.xml like wise. Could you please mention the config that you are trying to change? Is it a custom config? which config file contains it?

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaKarunarathna, i have to read a API value dynamically in the custom handler, it is not mandatory to read from deployment.toml file only.

Comment: Referred the below documentation for writing a custom handler. can u please help to read a dynamic value in handler from any config file in Wso2 identity server package. https://ganganichamika.medium.com/write-a-custom-event-handler-using-the-wso2-identity-server-eventing-framework-caa5dc9da8a3

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate your usecase properly with an example? As you have mentioned you have written a custom event handler to execute on user claim updates. That event handler logic is to invoke another API with the user-updated claim value. Am I correct so far? Then what kind of value in the config file you want to read inside the custom event handler and what is the usage of that value?

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaKarunarathna, please find the updated code above. I'm developing a web application in which i have to display the updated claim values in user's profile hence for displaying that in user profile i'm pushing the updated values in an API. I can't hardcode the API value in handler since it has to change for every environment. Therefore i need to read that API value dynamically. so please help here to read the API value from any properties file in wso2 identity server.

Answer (score 0):

Since the API path is required inside your custom event handler, let's define the API path value as one of the properties of the event handler.

Add the deployment.toml config as follows.

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "UserRegistrationCustomEventHandler"
subscriptions =["POST_SET_USER_CLAIMS"]
properties.apiPath = "http://192.168.1.X:8080/SomeService/user/updateUserEmail"
```

Once you restart the server `identity-event.properties` file populates the given configs.

In your custom event handler java code needs to read the config from `identity-event.properties` file. The file reading is done at the server startup and every config is loaded to the memory.

By adding this to your java code, you can load to configured value in the property.

```
configs.getModuleProperties().getProperty("UserRegistrationCustomEventHandler.apiPath")
```

NOTE: property name needs to be defined as `<event_handler_name>.<property_name>`

Here is a reference to such event hanlder's property loading code snippet https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/68e3f2d5e246b6a75f48e314ee1019230c662b55/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.password.policy/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/password/policy/handler/PasswordPolicyValidationHandler.java#L128-L133

Comment: Thanks for the much help @Anuradha Karunarathna